# Trying to change checkbox on record via visualforce + apex

Tags: apex, visualforce

I have the following Visualforce and Apex class.

I've got a command link sending params to an apex controller to change a checkbox (boolean) value on a record.

When I click the button it sets it to true, but when I click the link again I expect `project.isHighlighted__c = !project.isHighlighted__c;` to set it to opposite of what it is currently... Basically a toggle for the checkbox field.

Any idea what's happening here? Am I doing something glaringly wrong?

```
<apex:page standardController="Project__c" recordSetVar="Project__c" extensions="ProjectPlugin" >

        <apex:form >

            <apex:pageBlock title="Current Open Projects:" id="projectsBlock">

                <apex:pageBlockTable value="{!Project__c}" var="p" >

                    <apex:column headerValue="Highlight">

                        <apex:commandLink value="H" >

                            <apex:param name="projectId"
                                        value="{!p.id}"
                                        assignTo="{!projectId}"/>

                            <apex:param name="isHighlighted"
                                        value="{!p.isHighlighted__c}"
                                        assignTo="{!isHighlighted}"/>

                        </apex:commandLink>

                    </apex:column>

                </apex:pageBlockTable>
            </apex:pageBlock>
        </apex:form>

</apex:page>
```

**Apex Class**

```
public  class ProjectPlugin {


private ApexPages.StandardSetController controller {get; set;}

private Project__c project {get;set;}


public Id projectId {get;set;}
public Boolean isHighlighted {get;set;}


public ProjectPlugin(ApexPages.StandardSetController controller) {

    this.controller = controller;
    this.project = (Project__c)controller.getRecord();

}


    public PageReference processLinkClick() {
        project.id = projectId;
        project.isHighlighted__c = !project.isHighlighted__c;
        update project;
        return null;

    }

}
```

Comment: According to the documentation of getRecord method, only those fields which are referenced in VF page are fetched. [SC methods](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardController_getRecord.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Noticed my problem not long after posting, but here's what I did!

I changed my Apex Controller like this:

```
public void processLinkClick() {
        this.project = [SELECT isHighlighted__c FROM Project__c WHERE Id = :projectId];

        project.isHighlighted__c = !project.isHighlighted__c;

        update project;

    }
```

Comment: This change *technically* works, but you should be aware of what you're actually doing with your code; you should really figure out why using StandardSetController.getRecord() wasn't doing what you expected-- this means reading the documentation.

Comment: Also, there wasn't anything *wrong* with `project.IsHighlighted__c = !project.IsHighlighted__c;`. In fact, that version reduces the code you need to cover, which is a good thing.

Comment: @sfdcfox Thanks for your comment, I've been looking at [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.pages.meta/pages/apex_ApexPages_StandardSetController_getRecord.htm) and it says getRecord on StandardSetController is used for mass updates, so I don't know how I'd use the parameter to specify which record specifically. Can you give me an idea there?

Comment: in case you find the documentation on standardSetControllers to be mystifying (as I have), this https://www.developerforce.com/guides/Visualforce_in_Practice.pdf Chapter 4 is well worth reading

Comment: @crop1645 Thanks, much appreciated.